# Automatically Running a Script On a Server?

Tags: javascript

## Background

I have a few javascript scripts that I'd like to automatically run at a certain time on a server (e.g. I'm thinking of using Heroku). These scripts essentially add a product of my choice to my cart and check out for me (So I don't have to wake up at 5am during a release).

## My Question

Since my scripts essentially look at the form on the webpage, how can I do this from a server? Previously I was using it as a chrome extension and manually had to open the page to allow the scripts to automatically run.

Would this be possible on Heroku? I'm new to backend stuff, since I mostly do iOS, so I don't know much about servers.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this on StackOverflow.

Comment: You can't "run JavaScript on a server" to accomplish what you would by running it in the browser with the webpage open. You are better off sending requests from the server (Python requests library or even cURL).

Comment: By sending http requests can I fill in a form on a website, and auto check out (Assuming they don't have a direct api to use, for example nike or something like zara)?